# Matrix equation A*B=A

Tags: linear-algebra

If A and B - the non-zero matrix of the same size, and the matrix A is singular, what solutions does the equation A * B = A? Or B = I - the only solution?

Comment: If $A$ is singular, there are more solutions. (Consider an extreme case where $A$ is the matrix of all zeros - then any $B$ is a solution.)

Comment: There is a [way to calculate all solutions of an underspecified linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that there will in general be many solutions. Note that this is ultimately just a linear system of equation.

For a particular solution, we can simply take $B=I$. To construct general solution, it suffices to add solutions to the homogeneous problem. In this case, if $u$ is a solution to $Au=\vec 0$, then for any vector $v$, $B= uv^T$ satisfies $AB=0$.  Moreover, any solution to $AB=0$ is a linear combination of such matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is singular, the system $AX=e_i$ has many solutions which $e_i$ is the unit vector of proper size, and so your equation has several solutions.